# Links with mouseover to change one separate DIV content - mouseout to return a default

Tags: html, hyperlink, mouseover

I have links and I want to change the content above them in the separate DIV with mouseover.

see image of what im designing here http://tinypic.com/r/2l3ksm/8

There's different content corresponding to each link. On the mouseleave, I need the default News story with text & the image to return inside this DIV.

My code so far

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".mark").bind("mouseover", function () {
                var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("mark", "");
                $(".icontent" + index).show();
            });
            $(".mark").bind("mouseout", function () {
                var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("mark", "");
                $(".icontent" + index).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>


<style>

ul {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;



    }

    ul > li
{
    color: #dc3fb0;
}

ul > li > span
{
    color: #58595b;
}




</style>


</head>

<body bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
<table style="background-color: #FFF;" width="454" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>

    <td style="background-image:url(public-finance-bg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; color: #58595b; padding-bottom: 15px;"><div class="icontent1" style="display: none">Network Rail ordered to pay back<br/> £53m over late trains<img src="train.jpg" width="454" height="246" /></div>

     <div class="icontent2" style="display: none">
                    <img src="train2.jpg" width="454" height="246" />
                </div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #58595b; border-bottom: solid 2px #666666; padding-left: 15px; padding-top:5px;">Latest News</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b; padding-top: 12px;"><ul><li><span><a href="#" class="mark" id="mark1">Better Care Fund cash 'could finance hospitals</a></span></li></ul></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b;"><ul><li><span><a href="#" class="mark" id="mark2">Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</a></span></li></ul></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b;"><ul><li><span>Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></li></ul></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b;"><ul><li><span>Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></li></ul></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #58595b; text-align: right; padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">see all articles ></td>
  </tr>
</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So ... What does not work in your code ? You should also provide a live example for people to work with, see http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://codepen.io/pen

Answer (score 1):

try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/XqG4U/1/) :

what i dide is inside the  `<TD>` i put all the `<DIV>` tags that need to be showen inside with `display;none;` and one div as default and tgoole them on mouse enter

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. The only thing i have to work out now is when you mouse-over the links quickly the divs go crazy and two of them start showing up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I was tring your code.

The code work great but what happens is that you load the content above your links, so, your links is pushed down when mouse over, so the content hides.

You may put the content div at right from the articles list, so the code won't bugs.

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7dBC5/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.mark').mouseover(function(){
         var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("mark", "");
         if ($(".icontent" + index).is(':hidden')) {
             $(".icontent" + index).show();
         }
    });
    $('.mark').mouseout(function(){
         var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("mark", "");
         if ($(".icontent" + index).is(':hidden')) { }
         else {
             $(".icontent" + index).hide();
         }
    });

});
    </script>


<style>

ul {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
ul > li { 
    color: #dc3fb0;
}

ul > li > span {
    color: #58595b;
}

.divcontent { float: left; margin-left: 10px; display: none; min-height: 200px; background-color: #FFF; width: 454px; }
</style>


</head>

<body bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
<div style="float: left; min-height: 200px; background-color: #FFF; width: 454px;">
<p style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #58595b; padding-left: 15px; padding-top:5px;">Latest News</p>
<hr  NOSHADE style="size: 4px; color: #666666; margin-top: -18px;">

<!-- Your articles titles below here -->

<p><ul><li><span><a href="#" class="mark" id="mark1">Better Care Fund cash 'could finance hospitals</a></span></li></ul></p>

<p><ul><li><span><a href="#" class="mark" id="mark2">Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</a></span></li></ul></p>

<p><ul><li><span>Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></li></ul></p>

<p><ul><li><span>Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></li></ul></p>

<p><ul><li><span>Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></li></ul></p>

<p style="text-align: right; padding-right: 30px; color: #58595b;">see all articles ></p>

</div>

<!-- Your articles below here -->

<div class="divcontent icontent1">Network Rail ordered to pay back<br/> £53m over late trains<img src="train.jpg" width="454" height="246" /></div>

<div class="divcontent icontent2"><img src="train2.jpg" width="454" height="246" /></div>


</body>
</html>
```

It will solve your problem!